# Date value issue

Tags: azure-databricks

I have two columns called `(StartDate,NextStartDate)` and dataypes for both column is `date`.And the values are displaying like this

[image]

And trying to convert to `datetime`:

```
SourceTableData["StartDate"] = pd.to_datetime(SourceTableData["StartDate"],unit='ms') # with time
SourceTableData["NextStartDate"] = pd.to_datetime(SourceTableData["NextStartDate"],unit='ms') # with time
```

And i am getting error :

```
ValueError: non convertible value 0000-12-30 with the unit 'ms'
```

Please advise how it can be converted to datetime

Answer (score 0):

My code creates a sample dataframe with two columns (date_col1 and date_col2) of date datatype.
It then uses the **CAST** function to  cast those columns to the DateType.
And it uses the to_timestamp function to convert the date columns to datetime columns (datetime_col1 and datetime_col2),
These are added as new columns to the dataframe. The result dataframe is  displayed using the display function.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType
from pypsark.sql.functions import col
```

**create sample dataframe with date columns**

```
df0 = [("2022-01-01", "2022-01-02"), 
        ("2022-01-03", "2022-01-04")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(df0, schema=["date_col1", "date_col2"]).withColumn("date_col1", col("date_col1").cast(DateType())).withColumn("date_col2", col("date_col2").cast(DateType()))
```

**convert date columns to datetime columns**

```
df = df.withColumn("datetime_col1", to_timestamp(col("date_col1")))
df = df.withColumn("datetime_col2", to_timestamp(col("date_col2")))
```

**display dataframe**

```
df.display()
```

[image]
Displaying results of the DF:
[image]
**using SQL also you can do it in your datbricks:**

I am creating the dataframe as tempview with the below

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("Sample")
```

[image]

**And using the CAST function in sql to CAST the date column as timestamp.**

```
%sql
SELECT 
  CAST(date_col1 AS timestamp) AS datetime_col1, 
  CAST(date_col2 AS timestamp) AS datetime_col2
FROM sample;
```

[image]

There are several other date functions in pyspark.
refer through this [URL](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-sql-date-and-timestamp-functions/). It may help you.